# Rails 5/JS: How can I make validation errors available to my create.js.erb template?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-ujs

I have a model called `adventurer`. I can create one using a remote form:

```
<%= simple_form_for @adventurer, validate: true, remote: true, do |adventurer| %>
# ...
```

My `create` action looks like this:

```
  def create
    @adventurer = Adventurer.new(safe_params)
    @adventurer.save

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
```

I want to handle both success and fail outcomes in the JS instead of the controller.

```
<% if @applicant.errors.any? %>
  console.log('It failed :(');
<% else %>
  console.log('Success!');
<% end %>
```

Knowing that the above example works, I want to amend it so it can handle error messages.

The following results in an error in the console `SyntaxError: Unexpected token '&'. Expected a property name.`:

```
<% if @adventurer.errors.any? %>
  errors = <%= @adventurer.errors.to_json %>
  console.log(errors[:full_messages]);
<% else %>
  console.log('Success!');
<% end %>
```

Which leads me to believe I am not passing the Ruby collection to JS in the correct manner. How can I make `#errors.full_messages` availabl to my JS template?

Comment: I assume you're using Client Side Validations gem and could be interested to take a look on [this section](https://github.com/DavyJonesLocker/client_side_validations#enabling)

Answer (score 3):

1. `console.log(errors[:full_messages]);` is invalid syntax, there are no such symbols syntax in JS as in Ruby. It should be either `errors.full_messages` or `errors['full_messages']` if you want to access `full_massages` prop on an object in JS
2. `@adventurer.errors.to_json` will return a JSON like this `{"error_key1": "error_messsage1", "error_key2": "error_message2"}`. So there is no `full_messages` prop here as you see. But you can also do `@adventurer.errors.full_messages.to_json` which wil return full messages in array.
3. You need to interpolate this JSON as `raw` string: `errors = <%= raw @adventurer.errors.to_json %>` to pass it to JS properly